# Is my molly under attack?

Tags: health, fish

In January I bought a pair of black mollies. Today morning one (female) died, having her spine bent and her stomach and mouth turned white-yellow. Now the other is kind of in nausea - you know, not moving, sitting at the bottom of the tank.

Could anyone please tell me what's going on? It's not eating now!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a parasite in the stomach which causes cramps which lead to the bent spine. I had - maybe randomly - success to remove the bending and have the fish life for another year with feeding *Daphnia* in an isolation aquarium[1]. It's not too expensive and worth a try.

The question whether it's under attack is a separate one which you can figure out after the bending has gone, an attack is definitely not the cause for it. An attack or aggressive atmosphere might lower the immune system and made the infection with the parasite more easy, though.

---

[1] A separate cycled aquarium with the necessary equipment for the hosted fish (i.e. filtration and heating for a Molly). It can be smaller than the recommended size for the fish since the stay in it is only temporary (e.g. 20l for a Molly). Remember to acclimate the fish during the move by putting it in a container with original water and changing water from the target aquarium slowly over 30 minutes.

Comment: I actually keep it in a fish bowl without any filter or heater of any kind.

Comment: Then it will die soon if you don't change that. That's animal abuse. Any fish needs filtration and Mollies need a heater for 22 to 25°C. You need to learn how to run an aquarium.

Comment: So what should I do at this moment ? 

Comment: ChristyB.'s answer contains good recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

My best advice, change water as soon as possible with proper water conditioner to add more oxygen than it currently has, and if you don't have the funds to buy a new setup, check your local Craigslist or similar online classifieds to find a tank with filter, gravel, aeration, and heat as soon as possible.

Run to your local pet store and find an all in one medication to help. I have mollies and they absolutely love an extra dose of freshwater aquarium salt. It's cheap, it helps with many ailments, adding electrolytes to the water, soothes sores, helps to reduce fungal infection and helps with fin regeneration and fin health in general.

And I think you were possibly describing being lathargic versus nausea? Hope he's not regurgitating.

Comment: I change water every alternate day and I will be buying all the things as soon as possible.